# How do I properly stagger thousands of inserts so as not to lock a table?

Tags: mysql, locking

I have a server that receives data from thousands of locations all over the world. Periodically, that server connects to my DB server and inserts records with multi-insert, some 11,000 rows at a time per multi, and up to 6 insert statements. When this happens, all 6 process lock the table being inserted into.

What I am trying to figure out is what causes the locking? Am I better off limiting my multi-insert to, say 100 rows at a time and doing them end to end? What do I use for guidelines?

The DB server has 100GB RAM and 12 processors. It is very lightly used but when these inserts come in, everyone freezes up for a couple minutes which disrupts peopel running reports, etc.

Thanks for any advice. I know I need to stagger the inserts, I am just asking what is a recommended way to do this.

UPDATE: I was incorrect. I spoke to the programmer and he said that there is a perl program running that sends single inserts to the server, as rapidly as it can. NOT a multi-insert. There are (currently) 6 of these perl processes running simultaneously. One of them is doing 91000 inserts, one at a time. Perhaps since we have a lot of RAM, a multi-insert would be better?

Comment: Maybe you should prepare staging table without foreign keys and indexes

Comment: Maybe the http://dba.stackexchange.com its better suitable for this question... just maybe

Comment: What engine are you using? Is it HDD based, or SSD? What tuning has been done on the server? It sounds to me like it might have specs that are outrageous in some departments and yet completely inadequate in others. For example, using RAID-5 for the database will make write speeds absolutely abysmal. Have you tried benchmarking smaller inserts vs. larger ones? Have you watched to see what locks might be interfering with write performance?

Comment: Thanks Jorge. I'll do that.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what those Perl programs are doing. Are they doing 91,000 inserts in a single transaction? Are they locking tables? What table format are you using (MyISAM is terrible about locks)? What indexes are on those tables? How many tables are being inserted into? What does the slow query log say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question lacks a bunch of details about how the system is structured.  In addition, if you have a database running on a server with 100 Gbytes of RAM, you should have access to a professional DBA, and not rely on internet forums.

But, as lad2025 suggests in a comment, staging tables can probably solve your problem.  Your locking is probably caused by indexes, or possibly by triggers.  The suggestion would be to load the data into a staging table.  Then, leisurely load the data from the staging table into the final table.

One possibility is doing 11,000 inserts, say one per second (that would require about three hours).  Although there is more overhead in doing the inserts, each would be its own transaction and the locking times would be very short.

Of course, only inserting 1 record at a time may not be optimal.  Perhaps 10 or 100 or even 1000 would suffice.  You can manage the inserts using the event scheduler.

And, this assumes that the locking scales according to the volume of the input data.  That is an assumption, but I think a reasonable one in the absence of other information.

Comment: Yes, the locking does seem to scale as the loads increase. We have access to plenty of server resources. How does going through a staging db help? It still has to eventually do inserts cirrect?

Comment: @DougWolfgram . . . It brings all the data into the database environment.  This is usually a big convenience for tracking the transactions -- say restarting them, or seeing what data is being processed, or just managing the batches.

Comment: Yea, we thought this through. Seems like a good way to go forward.